# Derby database is accessible in razor sql without authentication

Tags: java, netbeans, derby, razorsql

I have designed a Java derby database application. It had  the dbproperties file. I'm creating a database file with these properties. Even it had username and password. The database is accessible in razorsql without any authentication. Suggest me where I'm missing.

[creating Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYrJz.png)

[image]

[dbproperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYrJz.png)

[image]

Comment: why don't you copy/paste the code?

Comment: To differentiate two classes effectively and to have a best view.

Comment: Are you sure your other tool is looking at the same database? When you specify "create=true" in your Derby JDBC Connection URL, Derby will quietly make a new, empty, unsecured database if the database you specify doesn't exist.